# CSS Opacity transition not affecting child elements

Tags: javascript, css, transition, opacity

I have an Opacity transition affecting a div element but it does not seem to change the opacity of the child elements inside the div. My understanding is that the property of the containing div should apply to all child elements as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the HTML and CSS:

```
.tabtext {
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 1s; 
}

<div id="smartITtext" class="tabtext"> 
<h2 class="tabtext">Some Text</h2>
</div>
```

Below is the line in Javascript which changes the Opacity:

```
document.getElementById(smartITtext).style.opacity= 1;
```

Comment: Where is the `text` variable set in your js can you show what it's value is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The property of the parent element should apply to the child element. UNLESS the child element has it's own property.

So if we have this code:

```
#container {
  color: blue;
}

.one {
  color: firebrick;
}

<div id="container">
  <span class="one">hello </span>
  <span class="two">World</span>
  <span>. <-- hello should be red, while world and this text should be blue</span>
</div>
```

play in jsbin: https://jsbin.com/focimuk/edit?html,css,output

So for a solution, try setting just opacity on the parent element, and add a transition to it.

Answer (score 1):

When applying your javascript code it will add the opacity style on the element in your html. So it doesn't overwrite the css style.

Here is an example on how you could let it work.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
  var div = document.getElementById("smartITtext");
     div.style.opacity = 0.5;
});
```

```css
.tabtext {
transition: opacity 1s; 
}
```

```html
<div id="smartITtext" class="tabtext"> 
  <h2 class="tabtext">Some Text</h2>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="change opacity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your child element has a specific opacity set on it. Therefore, it won't inherit any changes you make to the parent and your transition won't run: you've told it to have `opacity: 0;`, so that's what it will have despite whatever you set the parent element's `opacity` to.

That's equivalent to setting the color of a child element to be blue and setting its parent's color to red: that child element will still have blue text as you've explicitly told it to.

You will need to change that specific element's opacity to run your transition. Judging by your code, something like:

```
document.getElementById(text).firstElementChild.style.opacity = 1;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#' + text + ' .tabText').style.opacity = 1;
```

would do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly your javascript refences an id that does not match your html.
2. Secondly the id reference `("text")` needs to be in quotes.

Here is an alternative way to get the desired result.

```js
document.getElementById("smartITtext").className += " Active";
```

```css
.tabtext {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s; 
}
.tabtext.Active{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="smartITtext" class="tabtext"> 
  <h2 class="tabtext">Some Text</h2>
</div>
```